# How to change SVG scale(artboard)

Tags: svg

When you export an SVG with illustrator a viewbox is created that I think matches the Artboards size or the size of whatever element you are exporting. I currently have no access to illustrator but I will try it later on.

Anyways I think that whenever you export something the viewBox is being set to either the artboard of elements size. Let's just say I have an artboard of 160 by 160 px and I export and SVG that will have a viewBox of `viewBox="0 0 160 160"`.

If I don't mess with the viewbox I can make it let's say a 16x16 icon. In this case `viewBox="0 0 160 160"` still kind of translates to:

`viewBox="0 0 100% 100%"`

If I were to change the viewBox to something like `viewBox="0 0 80 80"` I get exactly one quarter of the image visible to me which makes a lot of sense.

Except the base image will always be 160 by 160 that is what the viewBox needs to be. I think you can probably change the default 160 by 160 viewBox if you export in of a smaller artboard. But how would you do this in code?

Hopefully you get the concept.

It somewhat relates to this althought it is a different matter.

https://css-tricks.com/svg-artboard-sizing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the `viewBox` alone. Just add `width` and `height` attributes to your `<svg>` tag. Here's a simple example:

```html
<!-- little blue circle: -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 160 160" width="16" height="16">
  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="80" fill="blue" stroke="none"/>
</svg>

<!-- huge red circle: -->
<svg viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="80" fill="red" stroke="none"/>
</svg>
```